# Only plot part of a 3d figure using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I got a problem when I was plotting a 3d figure using matplotlib of python. Using the following python function, I got this figure:

[image: figure1]

Here `X`, `Y` are meshed grids and `Z` and `Z_` are functions of `X` and `Y`. `C` stands for surface color.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(X, Y, Z, Z_, C):
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
   surf = ax.plot_surface(
           X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
           facecolors=cm.jet(C),
           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
   surf_ = ax.plot_surface(
           X, Y, Z_, rstride=1, cstride=1,
           facecolors=cm.jet(C),
          linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)                    
   ax.view_init(elev=7,azim=45)
   plt.show()
```

But now I want to cut this figure horizontally and only the part whose z is between -1 and 2 remain.

What I want, plotted with gnuplot, is this:

[image: figure 2]

I have tried `ax.set_zlim3d` and `ax.set_zlim`, but neither of them give me the desired figure. Does anybody know how to do it using python?

Comment: I don't expect this to be relevant to you after all this time, but just to be on the safe side: I updated by answer to show how you can get around the rendering bug with a bit more work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice conical intersections you have there:)

What you're trying to do should be achieved by setting the `Z` data you want to ignore to `NaN`. Using graphene's tight binding band structure as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# generate dummy data (graphene tight binding band structure)
kvec = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,101)
kx,ky = np.meshgrid(kvec,kvec)
E = np.sqrt(1+4*np.cos(3*kx/2)*np.cos(np.sqrt(3)/2*ky) + 4*np.cos(np.sqrt(3)/2*ky)**2)

# plot full dataset
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(kx,ky,E,cmap='viridis',vmin=-E.max(),vmax=E.max(),rstride=1,cstride=1)
ax.plot_surface(kx,ky,-E,cmap='viridis',vmin=-E.max(),vmax=E.max(),rstride=1,cstride=1)



# focus on Dirac cones
Elim = 1  #threshold
E[E>Elim] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
#ax.plot_surface(kx2,ky2,E2,cmap='viridis',vmin=-Elim,vmax=Elim)
#ax.plot_surface(kx2,ky2,-E2,cmap='viridis',vmin=-Elim,vmax=Elim)
ax.plot_surface(kx,ky,E,cmap='viridis',rstride=1,cstride=1,vmin=-Elim,vmax=Elim)
ax.plot_surface(kx,ky,-E,cmap='viridis',rstride=1,cstride=1,vmin=-Elim,vmax=Elim)

plt.show()
```

The results look like this:

[image: graphene full band structure][image: graphene Dirac cones]

Unfortunately, there are problems with the rendering of the second case: the apparent depth order of the data is messed up in the latter case: cones in the background are rendered in front of the front ones (this is much clearer in an interactive plot). The problem is that there are more holes than actual data, and the data is not connected, which confuses the renderer of `plot_surface`. Matplotlib has a 2d renderer, so 3d visualization is a bit of a hack. This means that for complex overlapping surfaces you'll more often than not get rendering artifacts (in particular, two simply connected surfaces are either fully behind or fully in front of one another).

We can get around the rendering bug by doing a bit more work: keeping the data in a single surface by *not* using `nan`s, but instead colouring the the surface to be invisible where it doesn't interest us. Since the surface we're plotting now includes the entire original surface, we have to set the `zlim` manually in order to focus on our region of interest. For the above example:

```py
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

# create a color mapping manually
Elim = 1  #threshold
cmap = get_cmap('viridis')
colors_top = cmap((E + Elim)/2/Elim) # listed colormap that maps E from [-Elim, Elim] to [0.0, 1.0] for color mapping
colors_bott = cmap((-E + Elim)/2/Elim) # same for -E branch
colors_top[E > Elim, -1] = 0 # set outlying faces to be invisible (100% transparent)
colors_bott[-E < -Elim, -1] = 0

# in nature you would instead have something like this:
#zmin,zmax = -1,1 # where to cut the _single_ input surface (x,y,z)
#cmap = get_cmap('viridis')
#colors = cmap((z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin))
#colors[(z < zmin) | (z > zmax), -1] = 0
# then plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=colors, ...)

# or for your specific case where you have X, Y, Z and C:
#colors = get_cmap('viridis')(C)
#colors[(z < zmin) | (z > zmax), -1] = 0
# then plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=colors, ...)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# pass the mapped colours as the facecolors keyword arg
s1 = ax.plot_surface(kx, ky, E, facecolors=colors_top, rstride=1, cstride=1)
s2 = ax.plot_surface(kx, ky, -E, facecolors=colors_bott, rstride=1, cstride=1)
# but now we need to manually hide the invisible part of the surface:
ax.set_zlim(-Elim, Elim)

plt.show()
```

Here's the output:
[image: updated version, no rendering artifact]

Note that it looks a bit different from the earlier figures because 3 years have passed in between and the current version of matplotlib (3.0.2) has very different (and much prettier) default styles. In particular, edges are now transparent in surface plots. But the main point is that the rendering bug is gone, which is evident if you start rotating the surface around in an interactive plot.

Comment: My second best guess, `plot_trisurf` also either produces this artifact (if I set the unnecessary values to `NaN`), or plots ugly horizontal lines at the threshold levels (if I just extract the *needed* values into new vectors, without any `NaN`s).

Comment: This is great! How about if I want to plot part of the surface based on another criteria. For example, I don't want to plot it based on `E`'s vmin/vmax but another quantity `F`'s vmin/vmax? Can ask as a formal question if that's preferred but thought it might be a quick follow up.

Comment: @jjjjjj yeah, it's simple. If you just want to change the color, nothing stops you from passing `vmin=F.min(), vmax=F.max()` or something. If you want to hide the surface beyond these values, you need to change `E[E>Elim] = np.nan` to something like `E[(E<F.min()) | (F.max() < E)] = np.nan` to hide those values. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ah yes, `np.nan`s did it, thank you! Would +1 again but already did :)

Comment: @jjjjjj not that I expect this to still be relevant to you, but I added an updated solution that avoids the rendering bug.

Comment: @jjjjjj no, that's just a necessity. The trick is rather than setting the z values to `nan` we create a colormap manually, and afterward set the colors that lie outside our region of interest to have 0 alpha (i.e. 100% transparent), without touching their colour otherwise. (The reason for the rendering bug is that using `nan`s will give you explicitly disjoint surfaces, and the separate surfaces get rendered wrong relative to each other. Using invisible patches fools the renderer, handling these parts as one big surface, rendering it right.)